# calculating flux using Gauss's theorem

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I need help calculating the flux of $F=(3x,4y,-z)$ through $S:${$z^2=x^2+y^2$ $z=x^2+y^2$}

the way I see it the first expression in $S$ is a cone and the second looks like a cup.

the cone and the cup meet when $z=0$ and $z=1$

it is easy to calculate $divF=6$

I got lost when I tried to find the limits of the integral:

$$\iiint_SdivFdS$$

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for the volume between the cone $z^2 = x^2 + y^2$ and the paraboloid $z = x^2 + y^2$. As you pointed out, the solid lies between the planes $z = 0$ and $z=1$. Note that the paraboloid lies below the cone because $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \geq x^2 + y^2$ when $z \in [0,1]$.

Use cylindrical coordinates to parametrize the solid $S$:

$$ S = \{ (r,\theta,z) | \theta \in [0,2\pi], r \in [0,1], z \in [r^2,r] \} $$

Thus,

$$\int\int\int_S 6\ dS = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^1 \int_{r^2}^r 6r\ dz\ dr\ d\theta. $$

This integral should evaluate to $\pi$.

Comment: thanks, this really helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The volume is between the paraboloid and the cone that intersect at $z=1$, so, in rectangular coordinates the limits of integration are:
$$
x^2+y^2<z<\sqrt{x^2+y^2}
$$
$$
-\sqrt{1-x^2}<y<\sqrt{1-x^2}
$$
$$
-1<x<1
$$